# Двоеточие в бессоюзном предложении

Tags: пунктуация

Скажите, пожалуйста: по какому правилу в этом предложении поставлено двоеточие?
"Мне предстояло отправиться в город, в котором прежде жили мои родители, приехавшие в него в 1995 году: этот год был для них настоящим испытанием".
Не должно ли здесь стоять тире вместо двоеточия?

Comment: Тире ставится перед словом "это" (не "этот").

Answer (score 1):

Для выбора **тире иди двоеточия** нужен контекст, без него смысл всего высказывания с этими знаками неясен. Или можно предложить два таких варианта:

(1) *Мне предстояло отправиться в город, в котором прежде жили мои родители, приехавшие в него в 1995 году (**этот год был для них настоящим испытанием**).*

(2) *Мне предстояло отправиться в город, в котором прежде жили мои родители, приехавшие в него в 1995 году – **кстати, этот год был для них настоящим испытанием.***

Comment: Не-не, скобки не подходят. В скобках самая ненужная информация. Разве здесь она ненужная?

Comment: Это  попутное замечание, которое в эту фразу плохо вписывается.   Без контекста здесь сложно выбрать оптимальный вариант. (А совсем ненужной информации просто не бывает.)

Comment: Не совсем ненужная, а самая ненужная, это разные вещи. Предпосылки для двоеточия имеются: в таком-то году, а теперь расскажем про этот год. Но таких примеров в правилах не нашёл.

Answer (score 0):

Конечно тут нельзя ставить двоеточие, но это и не вставная конструкция: никто не станет делать такое отступление в конце предложения, а потом продолжать текст, который будет никак не связан с этим отступлением. На месте двоеточия следует поставить точку, а следующее предложение начать с прописной.